# Xamarin.Forms Binding only updating ViewModel property with default values

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Consider the following somewhat complex case in `Xamarin.Forms` (tested on iOS simulator):

- One `GenericPage` superclass inheriting from `ContentPage` and containing a `BindableProperty`
- One `Page` class inheriting from `GenericPage` with a `ViewModel` which is bound to the `BindableProperty` using a `OneWayToSource` binding mode
- One `GenericControl` superclass inheriting from `ContentView` and containing a `BindableProperty`
- One `Control` class inheriting from `GenericControl` with a `ControlViewModel` which is bound to the `BindableProperty` using a `OneWayToSource` binding mode
- The `Control` class is embedded in the `Page` class using `XAML` and the `BindableProperty` of `GenericControl` is bound to the Property from the `ViewModel` class using a `OneWay` binding mode

[image]

I can verify that the "connection" from `Page` to the `BindableProperty` of `GenericControl` indeed works, as the `propertyChanged` method is invoked in `GenericControl` with the default value from the `BindableProperty` in `GenericPage`. I can also verify that the "connection" from `GenericControl` to `ControlViewModel` is working as the property setter in `ControlViewModel` is called with the default value from the `BindableProperty` in `GenericControl`.

**However, for some reason, the changes which arrive at the `BindableProperty` in `GenericControl` (either the default values from `GenericPage` or externally set) are not propagated to the `ControlViewModel`.**

---

Full Code is available under: https://github.com/mlxyz/Xamarin-Forms-Binding-Repro

GenericPage:

```cs
 public static readonly BindableProperty TestProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Test), typeof(Vector3), typeof(GenericPage), new Vector3(1, 2, 3));

        public Vector3 Test
        {
            get => (Vector3)GetValue(TestProperty);
            set => SetValue(TestProperty, value);
        }
```

Page:

```xml
<views:GenericPage Test="{Binding Test, Mode=OneWayToSource}" x:Name="Root">
<views:GenericPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:ViewModel />
    </views:GenericPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>

   <controls:Control Test="{Binding Source={x:Reference Root}, Path=BindingContext.Test, Mode=OneWay}" />
</ContentPage.Content>
</views:GenericPage>
```

ViewModel:

```cs
public Vector3 Test
        {
            get => _test;
            set
            {
                _test = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

GenericControl:

```cs
// bindable property and associated property is defined basically the same as in GenericPage except for propertyChanged property set and different default values
        private static void PropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("property changed"); // <- this is called with default values from GenericPage (1,2,3)
        }
```

Control:

```xml
<controls:GenericControl Test="{Binding Test, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
    <controls:GenericControl.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:ControlViewModel />
    </controls:GenericControl.BindingContext>
</controls:GenericControl>
```

ControlViewModel:

```cs
 public Vector3 Test
        {
            get => _test;
            set => _test = value; // <- this gets called only with default values from `GenericControl` (4,5,6)
        }
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete , so I could not find out the cause . It would be better to provide the full code or a sample so that I can test it on my side directly . In addition ,  here is a similar issue which maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62894322/binding-a-custom-entry-in-xamarin-forms/62894926#62894926

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I've pushed the code here: https://github.com/mlxyz/Xamarin-Forms-Binding-Repro

Answer (score 0):

I checked your sample and found out the cause.

When you set the **BindingContext** of **Control**

```
<controls:GenericControl.BindingContext>
     <viewModels:ControlViewModel />
</controls:GenericControl.BindingContext>
```

The binding between **Control** and **Page1** will not work any more.You need to handle the logic in **Control.xaml.cs** directly .

In addition , since you had set the **BindingContext** of **Page1** as **ViewModel** , why did you still binding the **Test** to itself ?

```
Test="{Binding Test, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
```

You should put all binding source in ViewModel and handle logic in it .

**Note:** The property in superclass will not available in subclass when using data-binding .  So you need to define them in subclass one more time .

So you could modify the code like following . I add a button to Page1 . When clicking it , the value of Test will change .

#### in Page1 .xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<views:GenericPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                   xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
                   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                   xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ReproProjectBindingIssue.Controls;assembly=ReproProjectBindingIssue"
                   xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ReproProjectBindingIssue.Views;assembly=ReproProjectBindingIssue"
                   xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ReproProjectBindingIssue.ViewModels;assembly=ReproProjectBindingIssue"
                   mc:Ignorable="d"
                   x:Class="ReproProjectBindingIssue.Views.Page1" x:Name="Root">
    <views:GenericPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:ViewModel />
    </views:GenericPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Button Text="Change Value"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    Command="{Binding command}"/>

            <controls:Control Test="{Binding Source={x:Reference Root}, Path=BindingContext.Test, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</views:GenericPage>
```

#### in ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using ReproProjectBindingIssue.Annotations;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ReproProjectBindingIssue.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public ICommand command { get; set; }

        private Vector3 _test;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Vector3 Test
        {
            get => _test;
            set
            {
                _test = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }


        public ViewModel()
        {
            Test = new Vector3(9,10,11);

            command = new Command(()=> {

                Test = new Vector3(12, 13, 14);

            });

        }

    }
}
```

#### in Control.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<controls:GenericControl xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
                         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ReproProjectBindingIssue.Controls;assembly=ReproProjectBindingIssue"
                         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ReproProjectBindingIssue.ViewModels;assembly=ReproProjectBindingIssue"
                         mc:Ignorable="d"

                         x:Name="CustomView"


                         x:Class="ReproProjectBindingIssue.Controls.Control" Test="{Binding Test, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
    <controls:GenericControl.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:ControlViewModel />
    </controls:GenericControl.BindingContext>
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label  x:Name="label"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</controls:GenericControl>
```

#### in Control.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ReproProjectBindingIssue.ViewModels;
using ReproProjectBindingIssue.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ReproProjectBindingIssue.Controls
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Control : GenericControl
    {
        public Control()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public static readonly BindableProperty TestProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Test), typeof(Vector3), typeof(Control), new Vector3(4, 5, 6), propertyChanged: PropertyChanged);

        public Vector3 Test
        {
            get => (Vector3)GetValue(TestProperty);
            set => SetValue(TestProperty, value);
        }

        private static void PropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
        {
            var control = bindable as Control;

            Vector3 value = (Vector3)newvalue;

            control.label.Text = "X:" + value.X + " Y:" + value.Y + " Z:" + value.Z;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it does not solve my problem however. I updated the code on Github. You will see, that changing `Test` in `GenericPage` will be correctly propagated through all bindings until it reaches the `BindableProperty` in GenericControl. So the binding between Control and Page does work.
However, the binding between the `BindableProperty` in GenericControl and `Test` in `ControlViewModel` does not work once the default value has been set.  In `Control`: `{Binding Test, Mode=OneWayToSource}` must be the problem.
Manually setting the text obv. defeats the purpose of MVVM :)

Comment: What I'm saying is: Why does the binding between the `BindableProperty` in `GenericControl` and `Test` in `ControlViewModel` stop working once the default value has been set once?

Comment: As I said , you need to handle the logic in Control directly .